# align-self для flex-элементов в колонку

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Имеется такой код:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content1 {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">lorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem lorem</div>
<div class="content">lorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem lorem</div>
  <div class="content1">lorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem loremlorem lorem</div>
</div>
```

Нужно что бы текст с классом `.content1` оказался внизу красного блока, как я понял свойство `align-self` работает только для `flex-direction: row`, но что предпринять в таком случаи?

Comment: Тоесть надо, чтобы был прижат к низу врапера?

Comment: @entithat, именно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Текст первого блока</div>
  <div>Текст второго блока</div>
  <div class="custom">Текст, который нужно зафиксировать</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так не пойдет, потому что мне надо именно последний элемент прижать к низу, а не сделать одинаковое расстояние между элементами, моя ошибка, нужно было в пример 3 элемента добавить

Comment: Обновил, посмотрите.