# align-self не спускается вниз

Tags: html, css

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.setting {
  align-self: flex-end;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        3
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link setting">
        внизу прикреплен
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[flex смотрю тут](https://flexboxfroggy.com/#ru) я пытаюсь спустить 4 элемент списка вниз страницы, [тут тоже пример был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/818427/align-self-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-flex-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83) и еще другие пробовала примеры, которые тут на сайте при задавании вопроса всплыли, но почему то последний элемент идем следом за тремя впритык ?

вот еще несколько сайтов, которые мне встретились по ходу поиска :

[the-echoplex.net](https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/?fixed-height=on&legacy=on&display=flex&flex-direction=column&flex-wrap=nowrap&justify-content=flex-start&align-items=center&align-content=stretch&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=200px&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=100%25&align-self%5B%5D=auto&order%5B%5D=0&flex-grow%5B%5D=0&flex-shrink%5B%5D=1&flex-basis%5B%5D=200px&align-self%5B%5D=auto)

[css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

вот еще вот так попробовала, тоже не то

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: green;
}

.foot {
  align-self: flex-end;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        3
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link foot">
        внизу прикреплен (!!!)
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

а надо вот как, но это уродливо с точки зрения написания кода

```css
.nav {}

.nav-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.foot {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        3
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link foot">
        внизу прикреплен
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, во-первых, у Вашего `.nav` нет высоты, поэтому последний пункт не может никуда опуститься (он и так в самом низу).

Во-вторых, положение надо задавать не блоку `.foot`, а последнему элементу `li`, поскольку именно на элементы списка распространяется действие флекса.

В-третьих, `align-self: flex-end` Вам не поможет - это просто перенесёт последний пункт вправо (поскольку у Вас `flex-direction: column`).

Необходимо использовать `margin-top: auto`

```css
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-item {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: green;
}

.foot {
  color: red;
}
.nav-item:last-of-type {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        1
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        2
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link">
        3
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link foot">
        внизу прикреплен (!!!)
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: прикольно, а если не ставить фиксированную величину, а считать в соответсвии с экраном например, то есть слева панелька такая на странице и величина этой страницы варьируется в зависимоти от того, на чем пользователь смотрит контент (телефон, планшет, экран компа итп)
а то ```height: 200px; ``` статически как то

Comment: @Dev18, если Вы про высоту nav, то её можно задавать в vh - это по сути процент от высоты экрана. Т.е. при 100vh Ваш nav всегда будет во всю высоту экрана (на любых девайсах).

Comment: ы ☺ круто, спасибки